# filter doesn't show the result on the dom Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

What I need to do is to display the filtered array in the DOM once I click on any value from the dropdown. The return from filtered function is right but I couldn't update the DOM.

**HTML CODE**

This is my side dropdown list that I take the value from

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="widget">
      <h4 class="widget-title">Sort By</h4>
        <div>
            <select class="form-control" (change)="selectChangeHandler($event)">
                <option value="Man">Man</option>
                <option value="Women">Women</option>
                <option value="Accessories">Accessories</option>
                <option value="Shoes">Shoes</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Table that shows the results on DOM take the value from above dropdown list to be able to show them by category. Unfortunately the DOM doesn't change (I used NGX pagination library), please see my TS code that sends the filtered array to the loop? So, I don't understand why it didn't update.

```
<div class="col-md-9">
  <div class="row" id="top">
    <div class="col-md-4"  *ngFor="let item of collection | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 100, currentPage: p ,id: 'foo' }">
    <div class="product-item">
    <div class="product-thumb">
      <span class="bage">Sale</span>
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="product-img" />
      <div class="preview-meta">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <span  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#product-modal">
              <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
            </span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!" ><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#!"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-content">
      <h4><a href="product-single.html">{{item.name}}</a></h4>
      <p class="price">{{item.price}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Type Script Code**

```
export class AllproductsComponent implements OnInit {

  allProducts:any[]=[]
  filteredData=[...this.allProducts]  

  p: number = 1;
  collection: any[] = this.filteredData;
  constructor(private _allproducts:ProductService) {
    console.log(this.collection);
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAllProducts()
  }

  getAllProducts():any{
    this._allproducts.getAllproducts().subscribe(res=>{
      console.log(res.data);
      this.allProducts = res.data
      this.collection =res.data
    })
  }
  pageChanged(pee:number){

    document.getElementById("top").scrollIntoView()

  }

  selectChangeHandler(value:any){
    console.log(value.target.value);


    console.log(this.filteredData);
    this.filteredData = this.allProducts.filter(key=>{

      if(value.target.value === "Man"){
        if(key.price > 20)return this.allProducts
      }else if(value.target.value === "Women"){
        if(key.price < 20)   return this.allProducts
      }else {
        return this.allProducts
      }
    })
    console.log(this.filteredData);

  }
}
```

I appreciate your help, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  allProducts:any[]=[]
  filteredData=[...this.allProducts]
  collection: any[] = this.filteredData;
```

you are initializing data before it is called from your api , so it's normal it will never work. You have to reinitialize it inside your method

```
this._allproducts.getAllproducts().subscribe(res=>{ ..});
```